# Unable to read blank spaces in string

Tags: php, string

What's wrong with this code. I want to read the number of blank spaces without using any built in function, but it wont return or read the blank spaces:

```
$string = "can you look into this??";
$i = 0;
$breakPoints = 0;

while ($string[$i] != '' & $string[$i + 1] != '') {
    if ($string[$i] == "" || empty($string[$i])) {
        die("cdsd");
        $breakposition = $string[$i];
        $breakPoints++;
    } else {
        print_r($string[$i]);
    }
    $i++;
} 

echo($breakPoints);
```

It's always going into the `else` part and never goes into the `if` statement. I even tried using `isset()` but that also didn't work. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: What is the expected output? Is it: `canyoulookintothis?`?

Comment: You're running into an issue with `$string[$i+1]`. When you hit the last `?`, it will hit an error `Uninitialized string offset`. I'm surprised you're not seeing it.

Comment: @aynber:  And they accepted the answer that still does that :-0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

spaces is not empty, it will tack size.
so use this

```
$string = "can you look into this??";
$i = 0;
$breakPoints = 0;

while ($string[$i] != '' & $string[$i + 1] != '') {

    if ($string[$i] == " ") {
        echo " ";
        $breakposition = $string[$i];
        $breakPoints++;
    } else {
        print_r($string[$i]);
    }       
    $i++;
} 

echo($breakPoints);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/699157)

or try this code,

use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$matches = " ";
$numSpaces = preg_match_all('/[ ]/', $string , $matches);
```

or Use this::

```
substr_count($string , ' ');
```

Comment: _PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 24_

Comment: silly mistake on my part, thanks. could not use in build functions . is there any better way to read the **blank spaces without using inbuild function**

Answer (score 3):

Just loop while the string offset `isset()` and check if it equals a space.  No need to do anything with `$i+1`:

```
$string = "can you look into this??";
$i = 0;
$breakPoints = 0;

while (isset($string[$i])) {
    if ($string[$i] == " ") {
        $breakposition = $string[$i];
        $breakPoints++;
    } else {
        print_r($string[$i]);
    }
    $i++;
} 
echo($breakPoints);
```

This outputs:

```
canyoulookintothis??4
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got your code right, you will always run into an string index error and you will need the isset() built in function to check before performing operations. 
In other words, the i for the index will eventually point beyond the last letter of the string, this will cause a PHP error. You can use isset() to check for it and break out of the loop. Example:

```
$string = "can you look into this??";
$i = 0;
$breakPoints = 0;

while (isset($string[$i])) {
    if ($string[$i] == " ") {
        $breakPoints++;
    } else {
        if($string[$i] != ''){
           print_r($string[$i]);
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
echo("<br />Number of spaces: ".$breakPoints
```